# How to resolve 'unsupported type NULL' error when running a datafusion pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am working on extracting schema from .txt data into bigQuery by google cloud platform datafusion.

First the datafusion was created in developer mode.

Second, I pointed to Google Cloud Storage, where data was stored. and I converted it to JSON format and achieved 100% of the completion(which means is no space in the column).

And I connected the bigQuery in the sink in the DataFusion UI.

When I depoly and run the data pipeline, it runs for about five minutes. An error occurs after that.

```
2020-10-08 01:19:54,947 - ERROR [SparkRunnerphase- 
1:i.c.c.i.a.r.ProgramControllerServiceAdapter@93] - Spark program 'phase-1' failed with         
error: Unsupported type NULL. Please check the system logs for more details.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported type NULL at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AbstractBigQuerySink.getTableDataType(AbstractBigQuerySink.java:488) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AbstractBigQuerySink.getTableDataType(AbstractBigQuerySink.java:484) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AbstractBigQuerySink.generateTableFieldSchema(AbstractBigQuerySink.java:379) ~[na:na]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AbstractBigQuerySink.getBigQueryTableFields(AbstractBigQuerySink.java:372) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AbstractBigQuerySink.initOutput(AbstractBigQuerySink.java:156) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.BigQuerySink.prepareRunInternal(BigQuerySink.java:104) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AbstractBigQuerySink.prepareRun(AbstractBigQuerySink.java:110) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AbstractBigQuerySink.prepareRun(AbstractBigQuerySink.java:72) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSink.lambda$prepareRun$0(WrappedBatchSink.java:52) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.Caller$1.call(Caller.java:30) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.StageLoggingCaller.call(StageLoggingCaller.java:40) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSink.prepareRun(WrappedBatchSink.java:51) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.plugin.WrappedBatchSink.prepareRun(WrappedBatchSink.java:37) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.submit.SubmitterPlugin.lambda$prepareRun$2(SubmitterPlugin.java:71) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext$2.run(AbstractContext.java:555) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.data2.transaction.Transactions$CacheBasedTransactional.finishExecute(Transactions.java:224) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.data2.transaction.Transactions$CacheBasedTransactional.execute(Transactions.java:211) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.execute(AbstractContext.java:550) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.execute(AbstractContext.java:538) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.BasicSparkClientContext.execute(BasicSparkClientContext.java:333) ~[io.cdap.cdap.cdap-spark-core2_2.11-6.2.0.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.submit.SubmitterPlugin.prepareRun(SubmitterPlugin.java:69) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.common.submit.PipelinePhasePreparer.prepare(PipelinePhasePreparer.java:118) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.AbstractSparkPreparer.prepare(AbstractSparkPreparer.java:85) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.batch.SparkPreparer.prepare(SparkPreparer.java:89) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.batch.ETLSpark.initialize(ETLSpark.java:112) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.api.spark.AbstractSpark.initialize(AbstractSpark.java:131) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.api.spark.AbstractSpark.initialize(AbstractSpark.java:33) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.SparkRuntimeService$2.initialize(SparkRuntimeService.java:167) ~[io.cdap.cdap.cdap-spark-core2_2.11-6.2.0.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.SparkRuntimeService$2.initialize(SparkRuntimeService.java:162) ~[io.cdap.cdap.cdap-spark-core2_2.11-6.2.0.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.lambda$initializeProgram$1(AbstractContext.java:644) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.execute(AbstractContext.java:604) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.initializeProgram(AbstractContext.java:641) ~[na:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.SparkRuntimeService.initialize(SparkRuntimeService.java:433) ~[io.cdap.cdap.cdap-spark-core2_2.11-6.2.0.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.SparkRuntimeService.startUp(SparkRuntimeService.java:208) ~[io.cdap.cdap.cdap-spark-core2_2.11-6.2.0.jar:na]
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutionThreadService$1$1.run(AbstractExecutionThreadService.java:47) ~
```

Thank you for reading. :)

Comment: The main error is "Unsupported type NULL at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AbstractBigQuerySink.getTableDataType". It seems as if the data being read contains some values not readable by BigQuery. Could you please send an example of the .txt file you are trying to read and the JSON converted data? In that way we will be able to see if there is any problem in the information being fed to BigQuery.

Comment: This issue has been resolved.
1. I have included formats that are not supported by the big query table. (array format)
2. The operation to replace all array formats with string and to create a data pipeline worked well.

Thank you for your interest. :D.

Comment: Nice to hear that you solved your issue. Can you please post the resolution steps as an answer to the thread so it can be helpful if other member of the community faces the same error?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and resolved it by populating the relevant schema fields on the **Output Schema** Section. This answer here -> [Google Cloud Data Fusion -- building pipeline from REST API endpoint source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996596/google-cloud-data-fusion-building-pipeline-from-rest-api-endpoint-source) also assisted me in the process